# One FK works, another gives error: "Multiplicity is not valid.."

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to add a FK to my `Contact` model using EF's Data Annotations. I have added two other FKs in the exact same way (BillingAddressID and ShippingAddressID) and they work just fine. I can't figure out why this new one refuses to work.

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BillingAddress"), Column("DefaultBillingAddressID")]
    public int? BillingAddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ShippingAddress"), Column("DefaultShippingAddressID")]
    public int? ShippingAddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreditCard"), Column("DefaultCreditCardID")]
    public int? CreditCardID { get; set; }
    public virtual Card CreditCard { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    [Key]
    public int CardID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add the credit card FK I get the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Contact_CreditCard_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'Contact_CreditCard_Target' in relationship 'Contact_CreditCard'.
>   Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the
>   upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

And I don't have any Fluent API stuff elsewhere fixing anything on the addresses. They just seem to work whereas the cards don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this is because EF can see that there are multiple Addresses for a contact (two of them, to be precise) and so is able to make some decisions about multiplicity that it cannot do with the Card.

With relationships, it's definitely a good idea to try and be explicit about it with the fluent API. In your case, you could try in the Card configuration to define it like this:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Card>()
            .HasRequired(card => card.Contact)
            .WithOptional(contact => contact.CreditCard);
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasOptional(contact => contact.CreditCard)
            .WithRequired(card => card.Contact);
```

This executes without error and will function mostly correctly. However, as it sees that a Card cannot be shared between multiple Contacts, it decides that the Card can be identified by the Contact that it relates to - why waste columns on unneeded keys? We then end up with a migration for Cards that looks like this:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Cards",
            c => new
                {
                    CardID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ContactID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.CardID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Contacts", t => t.CardID)
            .Index(t => t.CardID);
```

Note that the Foreign Key to Contacts is via CardId and not ContactId. The latter ends up being a useless column.

There is a way around this, though. Given that you've called the FK on Contacts the DefaultCreditCardId, it indicates that, in your domain, there can be multiple credit cards and that one of them is the default. If you accept this then you can change the configuration to be as follows:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Card>()
            .HasRequired(card => card.Contact)
            .WithMany();
```

Note that the `WithMany()` contains no property name - there's no way from Contact to get all the Cards via the model. What it does is to tell EF that it cannot identify Card by the ContactId from the related Contact as there might be multiple cards.

The resulting migration looks like this, which your initial requirement anyway (and I've included Contact to show that this has generated as expected):

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Contacts",
            c => new
                {
                    ContactID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    DefaultBillingAddressID = c.Int(),
                    DefaultShippingAddressID = c.Int(),
                    DefaultCreditCardID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ContactID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", t => t.DefaultBillingAddressID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Cards", t => t.DefaultCreditCardID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", t => t.DefaultShippingAddressID)
            .Index(t => t.DefaultBillingAddressID)
            .Index(t => t.DefaultShippingAddressID)
            .Index(t => t.DefaultCreditCardID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Cards",
            c => new
                {
                    CardID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ContactID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.CardID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Contacts", t => t.ContactID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.ContactID);
```

From the perspective of the code creating a `Contact` and `Card`, it will need to explicitly set the `Contact.DefaultCreditCardId` or `Contact.CreditCard` properties when creating a Card for a Contact as they won't be set automatically.

Comment: @Jason I've made a substantial edit. Take a look and see what you think. You might consider editing or removing your last comment given that it will no longer fully make sense in the context of the edited answer.

Comment: You did it! The `modelBuilder.Entity<Card>().HasRequired(card => card.Contact).WithMany();` worked perfectly. Thank-you very much!